# How to run Socket.IO application on my Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm studying how to build a simple application of a real-time chat. I found many solutions using Socket.Io and it's working perfectly on localhost, but I have no idea how to make it work on my server. Any suggestions ?

Here is my codes.

INDEX.JS

```
ar app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen();

function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
    function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('error loading index.html');
        }

        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data)
        });
    }
io.on('connection', function (socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io();
            $('form').submit(function(){
                socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
                $('#m').val('');
                return false;
            });
            socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
            });
        </script>
```

It's hosted here: http://stg.pixechat.com/chat/

Thanks

Comment: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" looking for http://stg.pixechat.com/socket.io/socket.io.js - Where is Socket.IO located? Is it in the place where the request is looking for it, and is it readable?

Comment: @SMcCrohan yes, it's in the same folder as the index.html

Comment: So, it sounds like it's in the wrong place. You currently have it in `/chat/`, and it's looking for it in `/socket.io/`. You can move it, or you can change the `src` to point to `/chat/socket.io.js`

Comment: I did. Still not working @SMcCrohan

Comment: Hit your URL above with the console open, and you'll see it's now complaining about not being able to find the module 'buffer'. I'm guessing there were some other supporting files for Socket.IO that didn't move, and now it can't find those.

Comment: Is your server running Apache / Nginx? Because maybe you just need to specify a port - app.listen(3000);

Answer (score 1):

You're loading socketio from a CDN now, which is good. However, your script looks like this:

```
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(){
            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        });
```

On the first line, I believe you need `io()` to be `io('http://stg.pixechat.com/chat')`